# variable not showing actual value when used in another variable

Tags: bash, variables

I've taken a snippet of simplified code from what I am trying to achieve.  Essentially, the location variable is taken from a configuration file and is always in the format of `/xyz/$id/abc` where `$id` signifies an application running on the server.

The code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the ID"
read id

echo
echo "Enter the location :"
read location

echo
echo "${id}"
echo "${location}"
```

So when I run the code:

```
$ ./test.sh
Enter the ID
xx

Enter the location :
/data/$id/app

xx
/data/$id/app
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the second variable to print `/data/xx/app` based on the inputs above.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`eval` should be of some help:

```
$ id='123'

$ loc='/data/$id/app'

$ echo "$loc"
/data/$id/app

$ eval echo "$loc"
/data/123/app
```

Note that `eval` will execute or expand *everything*, just like if you have typed the content of `$loc` by yourself. So you should take care with its content.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple [pattern replacement](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
id=123
location='/data/$id/app'
location=${location/\$id/$id}
echo $location  # /data/123/app
```

Comment: Thanks for the response....the previous answer works better for me but nice to know this method as well..